# Отступ после последнего li в ul. Как убрать?

Tags: html, css, css3

[image]

Проблема в ширине ul. Откуда берется отступ после последнего li в ul? Все padding и margin справа на нуле. Как можно убрать?

Comment: Надо пример кода, желательно на jsfiddle или чем-то подобном.

Answer (score 2):

Если нужна выборка именно последнего элемента вы можете воспользоваться псевдоклассом last-child

```
:last-child {
// тут ваши стили
}
```

Так же советую вам почитать про выборку с помощью псевдокласса nth-child()

Подробнее про last-chiild

> http://htmlbook.ru/css/last-child

nth-child

> http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child

В целом про псевдоклассы

> http://htmlbook.ru/css/cat/pseudoclass

Comment: тут скорее вопрос про сам ul, нежели про последний li

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно о каком отступе после последнего `li` идет речь, т.к. на скрине показан лишь весь список целиком. Если речь идет об этом пустом пространстве:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То с чего вы взяли, что это отступ? У вас указана фиксированная ширина для списка в 62.5% и это, вполне возможно, просто пустое пространство, не заполненное элементами списка, которые, скорее всего (судя по скрину) так же сделаны через `float:left`. Чтобы дать более точный ответ на вопрос нужно смотреть на стили самих `li` и родительского элемента в котором лежит `ul`.
Если задача стоит в распределении всех элементов `li` равномерно по всей ширине `ul` то можете использовать следующие стили для вашего элемента `ul`:

```
.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

А если задача укоротить сам `ul` то просто сделайте ему меньшую ширину.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, действительно дело в ширине и свойстав width и max-width. Думал обойдусь без flex, но он крутой и я буду его использовать тогда

Answer (score 0):

Говоришь, нет отступов?

[image: Говоришь, нет отступов?]

```
.main-nav {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Но это костыль, лучше внимательно просмотри все стили и найди что делает отступ.

Comment: Посмотри внимательно, я спросил про последний li. Т.е. правый margin, а его там нет, вернее нулевой. и padding нету, что можно видеть на скрине. Еще раз - только ПРАВАЯ сторона